# Objective-C Travis issue for boolean values in XCTAssertEqual: ("NO") is not equal to ("0")

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, travis-ci

here's my test code which succeeds locally:

```
- (void)setUp {

    restroom = [[Restroom alloc] initWithName:@"Target" andIsAccessible:FALSE andIsUnisex:TRUE];

}

- (void)tearDown {

    restroom = nil;
}

- (void)testThatARestroomCanBeCreated
{
    XCTAssertNotNil(restroom, @"Should be able to create a Restroom instance.");
}

- (void)testThatRestroomHasAName
{
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(restroom.name, @"Target", @"Restroom should have the name given when initialized.");
}

- (void)testThatRestroomHasAFlagForAccessibility
{
    XCTAssertEqual(restroom.isAccessible, FALSE, @"Restroom should have the accessibility flag given when initialized.");
}

- (void)testThatRestroomHasAFlagForUnisex
{
    XCTAssertEqual(restroom.isUnisex, TRUE, @"Restroom should have the unisex flag given when initialized.");
}
```

however, when Travis processes it, i get error for only the tests relating to boolean values:

```
 ✗ -[RRiOSAppTests testThatRestroomHasAFlagForAccessibility] (0 ms) (0)
  -[RRiOSAppTests testThatRestroomHasAFlagForUnisex]
```

*/Users/travis/build/.../RRiOSApp/RRiOSAppTests/RRiOSAppTests.m:91: ((restroom.isUnisex) equal to (1)) failed: ("YES") is not equal to ("1") - Restroom should have the unisex flag given when initialized.:*

...

```
✗ -[RRiOSAppTests testThatRestroomHasAFlagForUnisex] (0 ms) (1)
✓ -[RRiOSAppTests testThatRestroomHasAName] (0 ms)
```

*/Users/travis/build/.../RRiOSApp/RRiOSAppTests/RRiOSAppTests.m:86: ((restroom.isAccessible) equal to (0)) failed: ("NO") is not equal to ("0") - Restroom should have the accessibility flag given when initialized.*

I tried replacing `TRUE` and `FALSE` with `1` and `0` - but the same error came about.

Here's my *.travis.yml* file:

```
language: objective-c
install:
    - brew remove --force xctool
    - brew install xctool --HEAD

script:
  - xctool test -project RRiOSApp/RRiOSApp.xcodeproj -scheme RRiOSApp -sdk iphonesimulator7.0
```

And, I'm using Xcode 6

Comment: What is the type of the `isUnisex` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOL` is either `YES` or `NO`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `TRUE` is not the same type as `YES`, which is why the test fails. There is also `true`, which is a completely different type.

`TRUE` is defined in Core Foundation as:

```
#define TRUE 1
```

`YES` is defined in the ObjC runtime as:

```
#define YES (BOOL)1
```

`true` is defined differently depending on whether you're compiling as C99 or C++. You can look it up in `stdbool.h` if you're curious.

But in any case, you shouldn't test equality to `BOOL` (ever, not just in tests). You should test truth. The tests you want here is `XCTAssertTrue` and `XCTAssertFalse`. There are many "true" values that are not equal to `YES` or `TRUE`, which is why testing equality on `BOOL` is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I just randomly found the answer to the question myself while reading a textbook on TDD. I had to cast the booleans in XCTAssertEqual (e.g. `XCTAssertEqual(restroom.isAccessible, (BOOL)FALSE, @"Restroom should have the accessibility flag given when initialized.");`). The book is 'Test-Driven iOS Development' by Graham Lee - highly recommended!